# degree to become a statistician

Tags: careers

what is the minimum entry degree to be employed as a statistician

Comment: This seems off-topic.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me.  If you only have a Bachelor's degree, you will be lucky to find a position, most likely as a SAS programmer.  Most advertised positions are looking for a Master's or above.

Comment: @Mike It is a good question, but not in the scope of this site.